# Using A records instead of nameservers

Tags: networking, dns, web-hosting, domain-name, nameservers

I have 3 different websites hosted on the same server, but with different domain registrars. I realize I could use the server's nameservers for all 3 domains, but I was wondering if it would be possible to use the standard registrar's nameservers, but change the DNS' A record to point at my server's IP address.

Is there any advantage/disadvantage to doing it this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

there is two ways to point domain to server

1. domainname.com to A Record
2. Domainname.com to nameservers (ns1.domainname.com & ns2.domainname.com)

if you update A record with registrar for the domain, you can manage DNS with Registrar

but if you update nameserver for the domain you have to manage dns with your own server

this is the main differents